# Split one database text into 3 textboxes with DataBinding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, data-binding, textbox

I have database cells with 3 letters.

[image: IMG]

Which is connected to my textBox with DataBinding.

[image: IMG]

It works, but I want it to work like this:

[image: IMG]

To split the 3 letters into each textbox with the DataBinding. But how?

Answer (score 1):

I describe one possibility, but there are different ways you can achieve the same result. I find this one to introduce the least side-effect (if any) than other solutions that might try to use `Binding.Format`, and "push" the values into the individual character textboxes. I don't like such side-effect.

You don't specify it, but I'll assume you have a "data" object where the "Code_3" property is exposed. I'll also assume this object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, otherwise you'll have to explain how you implement Data binding specifically, and I'll adapt my answer accordingly.

The basic idea is to have 3 more properties on your data object, one for each character of the "code_3" property value. Another assumption is that it will always be 3 digits.

Finally, bind your three single letter textboxes to the appropriate three new properties.

How these properties are implemented could be to simply use `String.Left`, `String.Right`, or `String.Mid`, or maybe an index into the code_3 string value (mycode3[0] and so on).

Last step is to make sure you call the setters of those 3 properties from the setter of the "Code_3" property on your data object. This will raise the INotifyPropertyChanged event for each character, causing the Textboxes to refresh. You may want to set your Binding to "OnValueChanged".